# Jackson JSON Parser performance

Tags: android, json, performance, jackson, gson

Multiple posts on the Internet point toward Jackson as having better parsing performance than GSON, granting somewhere in the neighborhood of 20-30% speed improvement.

- http://rick-hightower.blogspot.com/2014/04/new-json-serialization-benchmark.html
- http://tuhrig.de/jaxb-vs-gson-and-jackson/
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android

Pulling out our GSON parser and replacing with Jackson resulted in a 7x slowdown in my project, with latency of over 300 ms per invocation.  The same parse job on GSON takes less than 50 ms.

I went through the list of "gotchas" on the Jackson Wiki, but nothing there stood out as a red flag.

- http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding

For example, I'm not recreating my `ObjectMapper`, and I'm using `ObjectReader` to read all the JSON.  Here is some sample code:

```
public class JsonParser {
    @Nonnull
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonParser() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(DateFormatUtil.getGmtIso8601DateFormat());

        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public <T> T fromJson(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        ObjectReader reader = objectMapper.reader(clazz);
        return reader.readValue(inputStream);
    }
}
```

The object above gets created once and is used for the duration of the app to translate JSON into POJOs.  A sample POJO can be seen here:

```
@JsonSerialize(include= Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ActivityEntity {
    public ActivityObjectEntity actor;
    public ActivityObjectEntity object;
    public ActivityObjectEntity provider;
    public ActivityObjectEntity target;
    public ActivityObjectEntity generator;
    public String content;
    public String title;
    public String verb;
    public String url;
    public Date published;
    public Date updated;
    // other properties omitted ...
}
```

What is being serialized is actually a list of the above items.

Here are my sample trace view windows from each run.  Note, this is *not* an anomaly.  I consistently get the same order of performance out of both Gson and Jackson parsing the same dataset.

Comparison was with Jackson 2.4.2 and Gson 2.2.4

[image: traceview output from Jackson]
[image: traceview output from Gson]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code looks correct, and even at its worst, Jackson should be no slower than Gson; and certainly not by multiples of anything.

If you were able to get a profiler snapshot for call stack (for running deserialization continuously for 10+ seconds), that would probably point out where excess time is spent, and could help figure out the culprit.

I would still double-check that `JsonParser` is not inadvertently constructed multiple times: one tricky case is for example via frameworks like Jersey (directly or via DropWizard) that may construct resources multiple times unless told to construct and use singleton instances.
I say this because symptoms just fit this case well, not because I doubt that you hadn't done due diligence.

Comment: I have a log in my code for each time the object is created and it only happens once at startup, so it is definitely not being created more than once.

Comment: The existing stack trace that is attached to the question is probably sufficient for investigation purposes. I'm not familiar with Jackson, so it means very little to me.  Almost 100% of the time is spent in DeserializerCache._createAndCache2 with the hot trace from there being BeanDesierliazerBase.resolve at 60%.

Comment: FWIW, that hot-trace is all inside the ObjectReader construction.

Comment: @markshiz it is unfortunately bit hard to read (although zooming does show some of it). Another possibility is if you could share a gist of object defs. However -- `resolve` (etc) really should NOT be there -- it's a one-time thing, and resulting deserializer is cached. Which is why I'd still suspect lack of reuse for `ObjectMapper` (or something similar)

Comment: Looks like I was getting a misleading trace from Android's traceview. The profiler was highlighting what I can only presume is the initialization trace.  When I run the code in a loop in a JUnit test and compare times, Jackson is roughly 10% faster.

Comment: @markshiz Ok that sounds more typical result. First call will have most of the overhead (construction of (de)serializers is bit involved in general, but Android's Reflection/Annotation access is notoriously slow, unfortuantely), but speed should converge quickly after that.

Comment: Note that performance on Android doesn't correlate with performance on desktop Java. Gson is optimized for Android, so that it's fast the first time you parse a document. Other parsers are tuned for throughput when you're parsing a lot of documents.

Comment: FWIW, discounting the initial parser construction costs, further traces on the Android runtime reveal Jackson to be much faster than Gson.

Comment: I agree with @JesseWilson, there are differing strategies here. One last note is that (yet) another possibility is `Jackson Jr` (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr) which also has lower first-use overhead, and is geared more for Android use cases.